# Laravel delete big data

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i have more than 1kkk rows.
What a best way to delete that using eloquent?

```
$data = Table::where('date', '>=', $date)->limit(50000)->delete();
```

Comment: `kkk` is a pretty awkward way to phrase it. Are you talking MMM as in "billions" or like "gigarows"?

Answer (score 0):

If you want delete all of it based on given `where()`, then then perhaps you could ommit `limit()`, and instead extract whole query into a [queued job](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#creating-jobs) to be run on time when system is least used. But it all depends on how often do you want to delete those rows, and wheteher you can make in *async*. Delete only returns you amount of rows deleted, so it depends if you need that number to be used during further processing of request.

Comment: I use jobs, but i need to delete only 1 million rows, il try do like this
`do {
    $deletedCount = Table::where('date', '>=', $date)->limit(50000)->delete();
    // break if 1 million deleted
} while ($deletedCount > 0);`
but that crash mysql with timed out error

Comment: How about chaining jobs? One job delets 5000 rows, and call another job deleting another 5000, passing `$deletedCount` via constructor.